# Showing two different activites on same fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Guys i searched a lot but didn't got. I have two fragment 
1) Form Transaction
2) Form Transaction statusin Form Transaction there are some fields to fill information and submit button. On Clicking submit i need to browse a file (which is on another activity but same fragment i.e Form Transaction). How can it be possible to have two activities on same fragment

Do i need to create another activity? And to whom will it extend?

[first fragment with personal information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBogE.jpg)
[image: same fragment but second activity]

Answer (score 1):

A `Fragment` belongs to a host `Activity` and not the other way round. An `Activity` can host multiple `Fragment`s.

Reads the docs for more info:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

In your case what it seems you are trying to achieve is to replace `Form Transaction Fragment` with a different layout and logic. You can replace it with another new `Fragment` itself.

Use a `FragmentManager` to replace the existing `Fragment`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

if (fm != null) {
    // Perform the FragmentTransaction to replace the Form Transaction content.
    // Using FragmentTransaction#replace will destroy any Fragments
    // currently inside R.id.fragment_content and add the new Fragment
    // in its place.
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new YourFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

Change `R.id.fragment_content` to your `Form Transaction Fragment`'s placeholder and `YourFragment` to your newly created `Fragment`.